# Does an SNS topic get removed even if there is no consumer subscribed to it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I want to compare SNS to SQS regarding dequeuing/consumption of the message/topic.

Does an SNS topic get dequeued/consumed if there is 1+ consumer active ?
Does the SNS topic not get "dequeue" if there is no consumer active ?
By consumer I mean any http endpoint, lambda etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure about if got your question.

If you are asking about the de-queue process for queues which is subscribed to an SNS topic; SNS plays no role once the items [messages] are transferred to the subscribers.

SNS doesn't persist the items / caches by itself, it tries to transfer the topic items to its subscriber lambda or sqs or email etc.

Please edit your question to be clear to get better responses.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to know if SNS stores the message if there is no consumer.

Comment: SNS doesn't do that. You can collect the items sent by SNS over an SQS queue then on decide later.

Comment: so I publish a message to an SNS  it instantly broadcasts it where there is an active listener or not. So the message is lost if no consumer was active at that time.

Comment: But I think setting a very large TTL is one way to cache it.

Comment: @Hexy, no.  Topics do not have consumers, they have subscribers.  If you subscribe to the newspaper tomorrow, you'll never receive today's edition, because you were not a subscriber when it was published.  The same is true of SNS.  Messages sent to a topic with 0 subscribers are immediately discarded.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you were referring to a message published to a SNS topic.

The Amazon SNS faq's have an answer to your question.

**Q: What happens to Amazon SNS messages if the subscribing endpoint is not available?**

*If a message cannot be successfully delivered on the first attempt, Amazon SNS executes a 4-phase retry policy: 1) retries with no delay in between attempts, 2) retries with minimum delay between attempts, 3) retries according to a back-off model, and 4) retries with maximum delay between attempts. When the message delivery retry policy is exhausted, Amazon SNS can move the message to a dead-letter queue (DLQ). For more information, see Message Delivery Retries and Amazon SNS Dead-Letter Queues.*